# Game generator - the same team shouldn't play more than twice in the same round

Tags: javascript, html

I'm still learning JS and I'm trying to do this game generator but I still have a problem, the same team shouldn't play more than twice in the same round. I appreciate it if someone could help me. Thanks!

This code is asking for the user to select how many teams are going to play and then asks for the name of the teams.

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#submitbtn')
const section = document.querySelector('#containertimes')

btn.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()

    const numTimes = parseInt (document.querySelector('#js-input-times').value)

    section.innerHTML = ''
    for(let i = 1; i <= numTimes; i++){
        const input = document.createElement("input")
        input.type = "text"
        input.id = "nome-time"
        input.name = "time-" + i
        input.placeholder = "Nome do time " + i
        input.required = true
        section.appendChild(input)
    }

    const submitButton = document.createElement("button")
    submitButton.type = "submit"
    submitButton.innerText = "Gerar Jogos"
    submitButton.addEventListener('click', gerarJogos)
    section.appendChild(submitButton)
})

function shuffle(array) {
    let currentIndex = array.length, randomIndex;
    while (currentIndex != 0) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex--;
        [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
            array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
    }
    return array;
}

function gerarJogos() {
    const nomeTime = document.querySelectorAll("[name^='time-']")

    let jogosPorRodada = []
    for (let i = 0; i < nomeTime.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < nomeTime.length; j++) {
            jogosPorRodada[i] = jogosPorRodada[i] || []
            jogosPorRodada[i].push(nomeTime[i].value +' x '+ nomeTime[j].value)
        }
    }

    let jogosEmbaralhados = jogosPorRodada.map(function(jogos) {
        return shuffle(jogos)
    })

    let resultado = ''
    for (let i = 0; i < jogosEmbaralhados.length; i++) {
        resultado += 'Rodada ' + (i+1) + '<br>' + jogosEmbaralhados[i].join('<br>') + '<br><br>'
    }

    section.innerHTML = resultado
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the shuffle function and I modified your code to make sure that a team can only play once per round and they will be able to play with other teams once. It uses a loop that iterates over the number of rounds. In each round, there is a nested loop that iterates half of the numbers of the teams for pairing. And after each round, use splice and pop to generate new pairings for the next round.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#submitbtn')
const section = document.querySelector('#containertimes')

btn.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()

    const numTimes = parseInt(document.querySelector('#js-input-times').value)

    section.innerHTML = ''
    for(let i = 1; i <= numTimes; i++){
        const input = document.createElement("input")
        input.type = "text"
        input.id = "team-name"
        input.name = "team-" + i
        input.placeholder = "Team name " + i
        input.required = true
        section.appendChild(input)
    }

    const submitButton = document.createElement("button")
    submitButton.type = "submit"
    submitButton.innerText = "Generate Games"
    submitButton.addEventListener('click', generateGames)
    section.appendChild(submitButton)
})

function generateGames() {
    const teamName = document.querySelectorAll("[name^='team-']")
    let teams = Array.from(teamName).map(team => team.value)

    if (teams.length % 2 !== 0) {
        teams.push('BYE')
    }

    let result = ''
    let numRounds = teams.length - 1
    for (let round = 0; round < numRounds; round++) {
        result += 'Round ' + (round+1) + '<br>'
        for (let i = 0; i < teams.length / 2; i++) {
            if (teams[i] !== 'BYE' && teams[teams.length - i - 1] !== 'BYE') {
                result += teams[i] + ' x ' + teams[teams.length - i - 1] + '<br>'
            }
        }
        result += '<br>'
        teams.splice(1, 0, teams.pop())
    }

    section.innerHTML = result
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Team Games Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Team Games Generator</h1>
    <form id="team-form">
        <label for="js-input-times">Number of Teams:</label>
        <input type="number" id="js-input-times" name="times" min="2" required>
        <button type="submit" id="submitbtn">Generate Team Names</button>
    </form>
    <div id="containertimes"></div>
</body>
</html>
```